# What is the Protoype of an Object when the Object is created using Object Literal/ Object.Create

Tags: javascript

Can Anyone tell me what will be the prototype of an simple object when that object is created using Object Literal Notation/ Object.create ? When i went through MDN Notes on Object.create it was stated something like below

```
var a = {a: 1}; 
// a ---> Object.prototype ---> null

var b = Object.create(a);
// b ---> a ---> Object.prototype ---> null
console.log(b.a); // 1 (inherited)

var c = Object.create(b);
// c ---> b ---> a ---> Object.prototype ---> null

var d = Object.create(null);
// d ---> null
console.log(d.hasOwnProperty); // undefined, because d doesn't inherit from Object.prototype
```

But Whenever i tried console.log(b.prototype) it gave me undefined, same with the case of "c" and "d" Object. I am confused here, if b's prototype is "a" according to MDN, then why is it giving undefined.

One more question, if b.prototype is undefined, then how come console.log(b.a);  is resulting 1. How is it inheriting in this case ?

Answer (score 0):

To get the prototype of an object, you use `x.__proto__` or `Object.getPrototypeOf(x)` rather than `x.prototype`.  Note that `__proto__` is now actually deprecated in favor of `Object.getPrototypeOf()`.

The property you are using, `x.prototype` is a property only found on functions. It is used to build `__proto__` when the function is called as a constructor using `new`.

Answer (score 0):

Prototype is not a member of instances only Function instances have prototype. Or you can add a `prototype` member but it wouldn't do anything for the prototype chain.

All objects have something called proto (a non standard property called `__proto__`) that is used to look up members not specified on the instance.

More information can be found here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/16063711/1641941